Swift Dependency Injection of generic class
I have ModuleA which defines the following class:
open class StatisticsManager<DealOptions> where DealOptions: Hashable {
     
   open func update(dealOptions: DealOptions) {
        fatalError("Implement in a derived class")
   }

   // Some other public methods which does not need to be overwritten in a derived class
}

In the same module I have other generic classes (most of them are UIViewControllers) which work with StatisticsManager. For example:
public class StatisticsViewController<DealOptions: Hashable> : UIViewController {

   private var statisticsManager: StatisticsManager<DealOptions>!

   public static func create(statisticsManager: StatisticsManager<DealOptions>) -> StatisticsViewController<DealOptions> {
       let viewController = StatisticsViewController<DealOptions>()
       viewController.statisticsManager = statisticsManager
        
       return viewController
   }
   // Some methods working with statisticsManager
}

So here I use explicit dependency injection to pass the statisticsManager to the view controller itself. However this is very tedious because I have a bunch of such generic classes and passing them as arguments of each create method is not convenient.
How I can create (or use) simple dependency injection framework where I can register all my dependencies and use them here instead of providing them as arguments?
I have tried Factory framework but I do not know how can register generic class as dependency.

A dependency injection framework would register a closure which creates your dependency (which is actually a factory function for the dependency) and which you specify when declaring the DI container (a global accessible singleton). So, each instance of a generic class dependency requires its own closure and an associated "identifier" where the dependent code can access it.
